# 1 fixed width div with two responsive div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am looking for a way to have a fixed width div centered in the display with divs to the left and right that re-size to fill the display.  I am currently accomplishing this with a javascript window.resize function.  The reason I want the divs to resize instead of just spill off screen is I actually want the images inside those divs to compress and expand.  Is there a way I can accomplish this with just css?

Here is an example of my current markup:

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="center">
      <div id="left"></div>
      <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0px;
min-width: 1024px;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
}

#wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: auto;
min-width: 1024px;
width: 100%;
background: #7c7b79;
overflow: hidden;
}

#center {
position: relative;
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
margin: 0px auto;
}

#left {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: -610px;  //I do want slight overlap
width: 630px;  //full width of image
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

#right{
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: -610px;  //I do want slight overlap
width: 630px;  //full width of image
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

javascript

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var browser_width = $(window).width();
  if(browser_width >1100){ //below this width stop compressing
    var width = ((browser_width - 1000)/2)+ 20;
    $('.mid_pat2').css({'width': width, 'right': -(width-20), 'min-width': 30});
    $('.mid_pat1').css({'width': width, 'left': -(width-20), 'min-width': 30});
  }
});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I can.  You can actually see the page in current state at http://www.envisiodesigns.com/test1/ but I will create a fiddle with less congestion to sift threw.

Comment: fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/jppower175/bNdnD/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `table-cell` (IE8+), or `flex` (IE10).

<kbd>[**Here's**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/QFKrL/)</kbd> an example with `table-cell`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">a</div>
    <div id="center">a</div>
    <div id="right">a</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
#left, #center, #right
{
    display: table-cell;
}

#center {
    width: 400px; /*fixed*/
    background-color: yellow;
}
#left {
    background-color: red;
}
#right {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

If the view port width is smaller then the fixed width, the table will not overflow, but instead the columns will shrink (and the fixed column will try to take as much space as possible)